# Vector space of upper triangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Good afternoon everyone, I am trying to calculate the following quotient vector space $\mathbb{M_3(R)}/UT$ Where $UT$ is the subspace of the upper triangular matrices of order 3. I suspect that any matrix $A$ can be written as a sum of an upper triangular matrix and a lower triangular matrix respectively, but I do not know?

My work:

Let $A$ and $B$ be two matrices such that $A,B∈M_3(R)$, We say that $A∼B$ iff $A−B∈UT$. But I do not know how to continue, that is, I do not know how to make this happen. I need to find the equivalence class of a matrix $A∈M_3(R)$. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Hint: $\dim M_3(\mathbb{R})/\mathit{UT}=\dim M_3(\mathbb{R})-\dim\mathit{UT}$

Comment: @egreg Thanks, but I still do not get this idea, can you explain me a lot more please?

Comment: The formula is the rank-nullity theorem applied to the canonical map $M_3(\mathbb{R})\to M_3(\mathbb{R})/\mathit{UT}$. Finding a basis for $\mathit{UT}$ is not difficult.

Comment: @egreg $\dim M_3(\mathbb{R})/\mathit{UT}=9-6=3$. So $M_3(\mathbb{R})/\mathit{UT} \cong \mathbb{R^3}$.  I need to find the equivalence class of a matrix $A∈M_3(R)$. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Every square matrix can be written as the sum of an upper triangular matrix with a lower triangular matrix having $0$ along the diagonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every square matrix $A\in M_3(\mathbb{R})$ can be written uniquely as the sum $A=L+U$, where $L$ is lower triangular with zero along the diagonal and $U$ upper triangular:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
a_{21} & 0 & 0 \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & 0
\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
0 & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
0 & 0 & a_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: How could this help me in finding the equivalence class of a matrix $A$ in the quotient? I'm sorry, I'm a beginner.

Comment: @DanielaRondón A matrix $B$ belongs to the equivalence class of $A$ if and only if they have the same “lower triangular part”.

Comment: Be this other exercise very similar, what if I want to see this vector space quotient $M_3(R)/S$?, where $S$ represents the set of scalar matrices of order 3. What would be the equivalence class of any matrix $A$ and what isomorphism would define?